# TKinter RadioButton not working

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I have been trying to get my radio button to work and I have looked at other questions but can't work out how to fix my code. It prints a blank space.

```
Entry4=StringVar()

def CreateNewJob():
  global Entry4
  window=Tk()
  window.title('Creating new job')
  Male= Radiobutton(window, text ='Male' , variable= Entry4 , value='Male')
  Female= Radiobutton(window, text ='Female', variable= Entry4 , value='Female')
  Mixed= Radiobutton(window, text ='Mixed',variable= Entry4 , value='Mixed')
  Male.select()
  Male.grid(row=4, column=1)
  Female.grid(row=4, column=2)
  Mixed.grid(row=4, column=3)    

  def SubmitNewJob():
    print('Selection: ' + Entry4.get())

  SubmitButton=Button (window,text= 'Submit', command=SubmitNewJob)
  SubmitButton.grid(row=15, column=1)
```

I have tried out all of the answers that you have all kindly supplied but I still get a blank space printed. Here, I have copied all of the code as the problem is probably in the rest of the code.

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")

#creating the frame and buttons on menu
f=Frame()
button2= Button(f, text= 'Create new job')
button3= Button (f,text = 'Close')

#layout of buttons on menu
button2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
button3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

label = Label( window , text = 'Please choose an option' )
label.pack()
f.pack()
Entry1=None
Entry2=None
Entry3=None
Entry5=None
Entry6=None
Entry7=None
Entry8=None
Entry9=None
Entry10=None
Entry11=None
Entry12=None
Entry13=None
Entry14=None

#allows user to create new job
def CreateNewJob():     
    window1=Tk()
    window1.title('Creating new job')

    global Entry2
    global Entry3
    global Entry4
    global Entry5
    global Entry6
    global Entry7
    global Entry8
    global Entry9
    global Entry10
    global Entry11
    global Entry12
    global Entry13
    global Entry14
    Entry4=StringVar()            

    def SubmitNewJob():
        print('Selection: ' + Entry4.get())


    Label(window1, text = 'Please enter information').grid(row=1)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input2').grid(row=2)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input3').grid(row=3)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input4').grid(row=4)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input5').grid(row=5)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input6').grid(row=6)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input7').grid(row=7)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input8').grid(row=8)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input9').grid(row=9)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input10').grid(row=10)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input11').grid(row=11)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input12').grid(row=12)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input13').grid(row=13)
    Label(window1, text = 'Input14').grid(row=14)

    Male= Radiobutton(window1, text ='Male' , variable= Entry4 , value='Male')
    Female= Radiobutton(window1, text ='Female', variable= Entry4 , value='Female')
    Mixed= Radiobutton(window1, text ='Mixed',variable= Entry4 , value='Mixed')

    Male.select()
    Male.grid(row=4, column=1)
    Female.grid(row=4, column=2)
    Mixed.grid(row=4, column=3)

    Entry2=Entry(window1)
    Entry2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    Entry3=Entry(window1)
    Entry3.grid(row=3, column=1)
    Entry5=Entry(window1)
    Entry5.grid(row=5, column=1)
    Entry6=Entry(window1)
    Entry6.grid(row=6, column=1)
    Entry7=Entry(window1)
    Entry7.grid(row=7, column=1)
    Entry8=Entry(window1)
    Entry8.grid(row=8, column=1)
    Entry9=Entry(window1)
    Entry9.grid(row=9, column=1)
    Entry10=Entry(window1)
    Entry10.grid(row=10, column=1)
    Entry11=Entry(window1)
    Entry11.grid(row=11, column=1)
    Entry12=Entry(window1)
    Entry12.grid(row=12, column=1)
    Entry13=Entry(window1)
    Entry13.grid(row=13, column=1)
    Entry14=Entry(window1)
    Entry14.grid(row=14, column=1)


    #closes submit new job menu
    def CloseNewJob():
        window1.destroy()

    #button to submit new job
    SubmitButton=Button (window1,text= 'Submit', command=SubmitNewJob)
    SubmitButton.grid(row=15, column=1)
    CloseButton=Button (window1,text= 'Close', command=CloseNewJob)
    CloseButton.grid(row=15, column=2)

#closes main menu
def Close():
    global window
    window.destroy()           
...

button2.configure(command=CreateNewJob)
button3.configure(command=Close)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: [This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm) little example should set you up

Comment: I have looked at this website and followed the same pattern it does but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Kindly update the code with what you have tried...

Comment: I have updated it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a few changes here & there. The first thing (that you already did) is using a `StringVar()`.
After that you might be getting:

> Exception AttributeError: "StringVar instance has no attribute '_tk'"....

What you need to do is call `Tk()` first before invoking `StringVar()`. Everything alse was just fine.

```
from Tkinter import Radiobutton,Button,Tk,StringVar
window=Tk()
window.title('Creating new job')
Entry4=StringVar()

def CreateNewJob():
    global Entry4
    def SubmitNewJob():
        print('Selection: ' + Entry4.get())
    Male= Radiobutton(window, text ='Male' , variable= Entry4 , value='Male')
    Female= Radiobutton(window, text ='Female', variable= Entry4 , value='Female')
    Mixed= Radiobutton(window, text ='Mixed',variable= Entry4 , value='Mixed')
    SubmitButton=Button (window,text= 'Submit', command=SubmitNewJob)
    SubmitButton.grid(row=15, column=1)
    Male.select()
    Male.grid(row=4, column=1)
    Female.grid(row=4, column=2)
    Mixed.grid(row=4, column=3)    
    window.mainloop()

CreateNewJob()
```

## Edit:

After your new changes : When you want to create a child window,you should use [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm).So,in your code,just do:

`window1=Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`

Comment: Your answer would be better if you described what you did. Otherwise we have to read line-by-line trying to figure out what you changed and what is the same.

Comment: ok did that..thnkx..kindly do edit the answer if you think i missed something ;)

Comment: I have added all of my code as I still can't find the problem

Comment: the code that i provided in my answer,what error are you getting in that? cuz it was running perfectly fine in my system

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use normal variables with Tkinter widgets. You must use one of the Tkinter variables such as `StringVar`, `IntVar`, `BooleanVar` and `DoubleVar`. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm for more information.

Note: you need to create the root window before you create variables.

UPDATE:

After a few days you posted new code. In this code you are creating more than one instance of `Tk`. That will cause your code to fail. What is happening is that the StringVar is associated with the first instance, but the radiobutton is associated with the second so it gets a separate StringVar.

If you need to create more than one window, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: I have assigned Entry4=StringVar() but it still printed a blank space.

Comment: @user3433940: you have to create the root window first.

Comment: I have added all of my code as I still can't find the problem

Comment: @user3433940: the problem now is that you create an instance of `Tk` twice. You can only create it once. When you create new windows you need to create instances of `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 0):

Radiobuttons use IntVars

```
def SubmitNewJob():
    print('Selection: %d' % (Entry4.get()))

window=Tk()
window.title('Creating new job')
Entry4=IntVar()
Male= Radiobutton(window, text ='Male' , variable= Entry4 , value=1)
Female= Radiobutton(window, text ='Female', variable= Entry4 , value=2)
Mixed= Radiobutton(window, text ='Mixed',variable= Entry4 , value=3)
Male.select()
Male.grid(row=4, column=1)
Female.grid(row=4, column=2)
Mixed.grid(row=4, column=3)....
SubmitButton=Button (window,text= 'Submit', command=SubmitNewJob)
SubmitButton.grid(row=15, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use `IntVar()`, `StringVar()` & even `BooleanVar()` for `Radiobutton`

Comment: I have added all of my code as I still can't find the problem