# tkinter - 2 out of 3 radiobuttons are ticked

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently running Python 3.3.2 with tkinter and I keep getting the same problem. When I create a new window with radio buttons, 2 out of 3 radio buttons are ticked but I am not sure why; I have tried playing around with my code but it doesn't seem to work. I would be very grateful if anyone can see why. Here is my code:

```
def shape_Menu():
    def triangle_choice():
        def updatetext(event):
            answer.delete(0, END)
            window1.update_idletasks()

        def check_Answer(event):
            if answer.get() == area:
                canvas.create_text(150, 95, text='Width='+str(random_number2)+'cm', font=('arial', 45, bold), fill=green)

        def correct():
            print('correct!!!')

        def incorrect():
            print('Incorrect!!!')

        window1 = tk.Tk()
        window1.geometry('875x450+375+325') 
        window1.title('Triangle')
        canvas = Canvas(window1, width=200, height=150)  
        canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=40, pady=35)
        canvas.create_polygon((0, 100, 50, 0, 100, 100), fill="blue")


        random_number1 = random.randint(1,12)
        canvas.create_text(150, 75, text='Length='+str(random_number1)+'cm', font=('arial', 10))

        random_number2 = random.randint(1,12)
        canvas.create_text(150, 95, text='Width='+str(random_number2)+'cm', font=('arial', 10))

        canvas.create_text(80, 115, text='Area = (Length * Width) / 2', font=('arial', 10))

        area = (random_number1 * random_number2) / 2

        random_num = random.randint(0,3)

        random1 = random.uniform(1,100)
        random1 = round(random1, 2)

        random2 = float(random.randint(1,100))

        v = IntVar()

        if random_num == 1:
            c1 = Radiobutton(window1, text=area, variable=v, value=1, command=correct).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
            c2 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random1), variable=v, value=2, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
            c3 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random2), variable=v, value=3, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)

        elif random_num == 2:
            c1 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random1), variable=v, value=1, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
            c2 = Radiobutton(window1, text=area, variable=v, value=2, command=correct).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
            c3 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random2), variable=v, value=3, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)

        else:
            c1 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random1), variable=v, value=1, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
            c2 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random2), variable=v, value=2, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
            c3 = Radiobutton(window1, text=area, variable=v, value=3, command=correct).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)

    def circle_choice():
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry('300x160')
        root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
        root.title('Circle')
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686587/tkinter-radiobutton-not-working?rq=1

Comment: It is a different problem, thank you anyway.

Comment: FWIW, you should _not_ have two `tk.Tk()` main windows in one program. Also, I can't see a `.mainloop()` call in your code. Please consider posting a [mcve] that focuses on your problem.

Comment: how do you run your code? you have many functions defined within each other and no indication of calling any of them except `correct` and `incorrect` as the command of the radiobuttons.

Comment: I can't reproduce on my mac (although I have no idea if I ran it the same way as you) Could you include your operating system?

Comment: are you using ttk radiobuttons or standard tkinter radiobuttons?

Comment: BTW, the `.pack` method returns `None`, so your `c1`, `c2` & `c3` variables will _not_ be set to the RadioButtons. If you need to name those RadioButtons create them and then pack them in two separate statements.

Comment: try this `v.set(None)` after creating the variable `v`.

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code as follows and do not see any problem with the radio buttons. not sure what you mean by "When I create a new window with radio buttons"

```
from tkinter import *

import random

window1 = Tk()
window1.geometry('875x450+375+325')
window1.title('Triangle')
canvas = Canvas(window1, width=200, height=150)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, padx=40, pady=35)
canvas.create_polygon((0, 100, 50, 0, 100, 100), fill="blue")


random_number1 = random.randint(1,12)
canvas.create_text(150, 75, text='Length='+str(random_number1)+'cm', font=('arial', 10))

random_number2 = random.randint(1,12)
canvas.create_text(150, 95, text='Width='+str(random_number2)+'cm', font=('arial', 10))

canvas.create_text(80, 115, text='Area = (Length * Width) / 2', font=('arial', 10))

area = (random_number1 * random_number2) / 2

random_num = random.randint(0,3)

random1 = random.uniform(1,100)
random1 = round(random1, 2)

random2 = float(random.randint(1,100))

v = IntVar()

def correct():
    print('correct!!!')

def incorrect():
    print('Incorrect!!!')

if random_num == 1:
    c1 = Radiobutton(window1, text=area, variable=v, value=1, command=correct).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
    c2 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random1), variable=v, value=2, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
    c3 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random2), variable=v, value=3, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)

elif random_num == 2:
    c1 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random1), variable=v, value=1, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
    c2 = Radiobutton(window1, text=area, variable=v, value=2, command=correct).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
    c3 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random2), variable=v, value=3, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)

else:
    c1 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random1), variable=v, value=1, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
    c2 = Radiobutton(window1, text=(random2), variable=v, value=2, command=incorrect).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)
    c3 = Radiobutton(window1, text=area, variable=v, value=3, command=correct).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=50, pady=25)

window1.mainloop()
```

please elaborate further and/or provide a working sample of code so we can hel further troubleshoot.

Thanks